# How do I setup CRM 2011 to move a Lead into an Opportunity?

Tags: dynamics-crm

Not much more info I can give. I'm new to CRM. I want to setup things so a Lead automatically gets turned into an Opportunity and then gets removed from the Lead when a specific field is set to a specific value. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Javascript, C# (through plug-ins) or Workflow.

You can set a workflow when a lead is assigned automatically create a Opportunity and other workflow when a specific field change and the value is x remove the reference of Lead.

This [tool](http://crm2011workflowutils.codeplex.com/documentation) can help you.

If you go to a manual workflow you need create a contact with information of lead, create opportunity record with the previous contact and change the state of lead to qualified.

Comment: Did you mean to say "Contact"? Why would I need to create a new Contact? Did you mean "Activity" or something?

Comment: Contact or Account. Lead at least in my company is a potencial customer when we qualified to Opportunity we create a Contact or Account based in information of Lead.

Comment: I actually just learned that, out of the box, CRM does the work for you. I didn't know that just clicking "Qualify" does most of the heavy lifting that I thought I had to do manually. There are only a few simple wires I need to connect behind the scenes for custom field. Thanks man.